We won't/ don't make so much waste if people don't use/use single-use plastic
I am in doubt regarding the next grammar exercise, to my ears the sentence 'We don't make so much waste if people don't use single-use plastic' makes sense as a zero conditional sentence as both verbs are in the simple present tense, but the sentence 'We won't make so much waste if people don't use single-use plastic' also makes sense as a first conditional sentence so my guess is that both options are Ok, Am I right?
I found that the word combination 'make waste' is possible, so I do not
understand why it would be wrong. 

The version with "won't" is probably more natural, but it depends on the context (have you already reduced the amount of plastic?) Not a great question.

Might you please let me know what do you mean by not a 'great' question?

The OP has asked whether both the Zero and First Conditional could be used in this sentence:

We won't/don't make so much waste if people don't use/use single-use plastic.

The best choice is the  First Conditional:

"We won't make so much waste if people don't use single-use plastic."

This doesn't mean the Zero Conditional is ungrammatical. However, based on common usage and context, the First Conditional is more appropriate.

I. The Main Difference:.
The main difference between zero conditional and first conditional is that

zero conditional sentences express general truths or known facts, while.
first conditional sentences express possible future events or actions that are likely to happen:


II. Why the First Conditional Fits Better:
The sentence describes a future possibility (reducing waste) that depends on a specific action in the present or future (people avoiding single-use plastic).
It emphasizes:

The potential for change.
The cause-and-effect relationship between the condition (if people don't use single-use plastic) and the likely outcome (we won't make so much waste).

By choosing the First Conditional, the sentence highlights a call to action and the impact of human behavior on waste reduction, aligning better with the context of encouraging environmentally friendly practices.

Thank you! That's a perfect explenation
